# ASP.NET error on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis

Everything was fine on my workstation by testing localhost of my asp.net website using VS Express for Web 2012 with framework 4.5. I move my ASP.NET files to IIS Windows Server 2008 R2 using Remote Desktop Connection, then I test it there on localhost and it work fine. When I am ready to upload to IIS to test website with Application pool of ASP.NET Framwork Version 4.0, I got an Configuration error on website say that allowDefinition='MachineToApplication',

```
</controls>
</pages>
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

It come from Web.Config file.

I don't know why I got error is it because I move my files from workstation or is it because my 4.5 framework do not match with IIS 4.0 framework. If IIS need to be upgraded then how or it can be easy modify from web.config? I don't want to change my 4.5 to 4.0 because it will screw up the coding and make it worse.

Comment: Please give us more information about error. (Error description, error code, etc.)

Comment: Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error says, you need to convert your virtual directory to Application.

If you are using IIS 7.0 and greater, please follow this steps:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Locate your web site root directory (Probably your web site is hosted in Default web site)
3. Open context menu and choose Convert To Application.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Done that with deafualtapppool(ASP.NET v2.0) then new error show up that says, Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error: 


Line 22:   -->
Line 23:   <system.web>
Line 24:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
Line 25:       <assemblies>
Line 26:         <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />

Comment: It seem like IIS features support .NET Framework 3.5.1 or is it because of application pool which support v2.0?

Comment: You have specified targetFramework="4.5" in your web.config file, but the Application pool has different version specified. Check application pool's .Net framework version. It must be 4.0. If it still fails, then you need to register it.

Comment: To register .net framework 4.0 you need  regiis.exe. Please see this link for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok, I changed from defaultAppPool(v2.0) to ASP.NET v4.0. Got new error on website that say, Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'. 
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution ahead by add codes on html and plus add authority on SQL Server. Thank